# Issues with CSS checkbox checked not working in my header

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox and label in my header im using for a side menu.

However, its not working and the selector of being checked isn't working.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/jpjL3hhp/

That should when clicked show a side bar.

However, it works here when my header isn't involved in the code: https://jsfiddle.net/jpjL3hhp/1/

What is causing the problem?

Working code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse_icon">
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">Show Menu</label>
<div class="side-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not working:

```
<header>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse_icon">
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">Show Menu</label>
<div class="side-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</header>
```

This is used for the check:

```
#menu_collapse_icon:checked ~ .side-navigation {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your HTML structure.

You are using `#menu_collapse_icon:checked ~ .side-navigation` as the selector. 
In the non-working example where you integrated with all the `header` it doesn't work because your `.side-navigation` isn't being selected since its not in the same level as `#menu_collapse_icon`.

So if you place the `.side-navigation` in the same level as `#menu_collapse_icon` it will work.

Like this:

```css
.side-navigation {
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 106px;
  margin-right: -200px;
  transition: margin-right 0.5s ease;
  position: fixed;
}
#menu_collapse_icon:checked ~ .side-navigation {
  margin-right: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
header nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="max-container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_collapse_icon">
    <label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">
      Show Menu
    </label>
    <div class="side-navigation">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Login</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Jobs</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Employers</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. To keep this how I wanted, I ended up just moving the checkbox itself.